# How can I get my CarrierWave model to return the full URL to me in a test?

Tags: carrierwave

Trying to test a `carrierwave` model is really difficult. I configured my test environment like this:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
    config.fog_directory   = BUCKET                # required
    config.fog_public      = false                 # optional, defaults to true
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'Local',         # required
      :local_root             => LOCAL_ROOT,    # required
      :endpoint               => "http://localhost:3000" # required
    }
  end
else
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :fog
    config.max_file_size = 1.gigabytes        # defaults to 5.megabytes
    config.fog_directory   = BUCKET                # required
    config.fog_public      = false                 # optional, defaults to true
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => PROVIDER,         # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => access_key_id,    # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => secret_access_key # required
    }
  end
end
```

and it works great for testing uploads. Makes it difficult for testing downloads though.

Here is a simple test:

```
require "test_helper"

class UploadTests < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  let(:user) { User.me }
  let(:repo) { Repository.first }
  let(:sub) { user.subscriptions.where(repository_id: repo).first}

  it "uploads a CSV file and lets me read it" do

    filename = Rails.root.join("test/testfiles/product_upload_test.csv").to_s
    upload = sub.uploads.new
    File.open(filename) do |f|
      upload.text_file_name = f
    end
    upload.save!

  end

end
```

All very simple. But what I want to do is read the file from the model. In other words, call some CarrierWave API that lets me grab the file and read it.

In production, I store everything on S3. In test, everything is in a local file. And I set `local_root` to be my app's `public` directory.

`CarrierWave` only reports the `url` as the path, but doesn't include the `local_root`. I don't feel that it is my job to manually construct the path to a file that I want to read from `CarrierWave`. How/Where the file is stored should be hidden from my test... I should have to construct that path.

But I don't know what else to do. All I want to do is read that file.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my test configuration to the following:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :file
  config.enable_processing = false
  config.fog_directory     = BUCKET                # required
  config.fog_public        = true                 # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'Local',         # required
    :local_root             => LOCAL_ROOT,    # required
    :endpoint               => LOCAL_ROOT # required
  }
end
```

and now the full url is returned.